# Normalizing the output of your rf-idf matrix

Tags: python, tf-idf

I am following this excellent tutorial: http://blog.christianperone.com/2011/10/machine-learning-text-feature-extraction-tf-idf-part-ii/

However there is one part that I do not get:

If the output of a matrix multiplication in tf-idf is this

```
[(0, -0.41, -0.41, 0), (0, -0.81, -0.4, 0)]
```

Then how do you end up with this matrix

```
[(0, -0.7, -0.7, 0), (0, -0.89, -0.44, 0)]
```

After applying the normalisation proces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalization gives unit norm. Thus $2*0.7^2 \approx 0.89^2 + 0.44^2 \approx 1$ (it appears that your output is truncated after 2 digits, and not rounded).